# Complexity of the TSP for hypercube graphs

Tags: computational-complexity, traveling-salesman-problem, hypercube

**Question:**

what is known about the complexity of finding the Hamilton cycle of minimum weight in graphs that resemble hypercubes with weighted edges?

Comment: What does "resemble" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wanted to express that the graph can be *interpreted* as the topological abstraction of a hypercube's, skeleton structure., Apparently "resembles" isn't the right way to express that (I'm not a native English speaker). Maybe "illustrates" might be an alternative way to express what I had in mind in the sense of René Magritte's "[Ceci n'est pas une pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)"